# How to retain double quotes while loading a json in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, yaml

Dumping JSON using YAML,

```
c= {"a":1} 
d = yaml.dump(c)
```

Loading JSON using YAML

```
yaml.load(d) 
{'a': 1} # double quotes is lost
```

How to ensure that the output of the load has double quotes ?

Note: I tried json and simplejson also, all behave the same way.

Comment: Why do you need exactly double quotes? As far as I know in python there is no difference between double and single quotes.

Comment: YAML and JSON are formats for data. The quotes are not part of the data. The data is "a dictionary containing the numeric value one under a key that is one-character string, a". If you want to preserve your YAML/JSON as-is, don't parse it, just treat it as a string.

Comment: @Nurzhan data has to be returned as response  for a request, in the client side, the single quotes is not recognized as json.

Comment: for Python there is no difference between single and double quotes. If you have to return response as JSON string then use `json` module (`json.dumps({'a': 1})`) - it will create correct JSON string - with double quotes. Some frameworks have build-in function to generate JSON response - they use the same `json` module in background.

Answer (score 3):

For Python there is no difference between single and double quotes.

If you need response as JSON string then use standard `json` module - it will create string with correctly formated JSON - with double quotes.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a': 1})
'{"a": 1}'
```

Some frameworks or modules (as `requests`) have built-in functions to 
send correctly-formated JSON (they may use standard `json` module in background) so don't have to do it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
c = {"a":1} 
d = yaml.dump(c)
```

doesn't dump JSON, it dumps a python `dict` as YAML. Use `json.dumps()` to make a JSON string from the `dict` and then optionally load/dump as YAML and preserve the double quotes by specifying `preserver_quotes` while loading:

```
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml

c= {"a":1}
json_string = json.dumps(c)
print(json_string)
print('---------')

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(json_string, preserve_quotes=True)
data['a'] = 3
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

that will print:

```
{"a": 1}
---------
{"a": 3}
```